# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript: Not found"

Tags: typescript, react-native

After uninstalling the `react-native-cli`
i run this command to initiate a RN project with typescript template:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

but i got this error:

> warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom
>
> > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()              error An unexpected error occurred:
> >     "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript:
> >     Not found".info  If you think this is a bug, please open .....
> >     [1/2] Removing module
> >     react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript...
> >     error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
> >     info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/remove for documentation
> >     about this command.                                              warn
> >     Failed to clean up template temp files in
> >     node_modules/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript.
> >     This is not a critical error, you can work on your app.
> >     (node:8548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed:
> >     yarn add react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved: i had to remove react native cli using yarn too

> yarn remove global react-native-cli

Answer (score 20):

Remove the legacy react-native-cli

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

Install new one from "react-native-community":

`npm i -g @react-native-community/cli`

after that, init the Project with:

`npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

Answer (score 5):

This will also help, `--ignore-existing`

```
npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

### Best solution I found

Remove

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

Create the folder where the project will be

`mkdir [folder name] && cd [folder name]`

Install the dependencies and everything will work

```
yarn init
yarn add react-native
yarn react-native init [Project Name] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with Centos 7, it must be executed as root

```
npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript
```

in the location where the project needs to be created and then `chown user -R folder`, and in this way accepts the `yarn add react-native- template-typescript` without problems.